# How to count no. of documents in MongoDB collection using Node.Js ?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have data in MongoDB and i want to return document count based on user input.But every time i am getting **Count:0** even though i have document present in database matched to user input.

Below is my code kindly correct me what i am doing wrong:

```
 const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const mongoClient = require("mongodb").mongoClient;

 var app = express();
 var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 var url = "http://localhost:3000/";

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

 app.post('/finish',(req,res) =>{

 mongoClient.connect(url,(err,db) => {

           if(err){
              console.log("Error:" +err);
            }

          else{

             var obj = {Name:req.body.name};

             var collect = db.db("Tiffino").collection("Users"); 

             var cnt = collect.find({Name:obj}).count.then((count)=>{

                   console.log("Count:" +count);
               }); 

            }
    }); 

 });

  app.listen(port,(req,res) => {

        console.log("App is running at:" +port);
   });
```

OUTPUT 
 Count:0

Comment: How looks like the schema in your Users collection?, moreover Make sure if your query is executed well before to do count.

Comment: Is my code correct...

Comment: Got that  in place of collect.find({Name:obj})  it should be collect.find({Name:obj.name}).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is mixing 2 different commands `collect.find({Name:obj})` and `collect.count()`.
First command returns the array of documents based on your query, while the second one gives you the total count of documents in that particular collection and `not` the count of your queried documents.
What you are aiming can simply be achieved by:

```js
collect.find({Name:obj}).then((docs)=>{
  console.log("Count:" docs.length);
});
```